# Rank the equal values of a dataset

Tags: sql, sas

I'm new to programming in sas and I had a question regarding this topic.

I have an input table like this

```
  CODE DESCRIPTION   COUNT
  NULL    KIT-KAT      3           
  NULL    KIT-KAT      3           
  NULL    KIT-KAT      3           
  NULL    FERRERO      2           
  NULL    FERRERO      1
```

and I would like to have an output table like this:

```
  CODE DESCRIPTION   COUNT  COLUMN_I_WANT
  NULL    KIT-KAT      3           1
  NULL    KIT-KAT      3           2
  NULL    KIT-KAT      3           3
  NULL    FERRERO      2           1
  NULL    FERRERO      1           2
```

The problem is that I have tried to group with a rank, I have used monotonic and I have done several things but none of them work for me, I want it to count the equal values for a field but not to repeat the value, but to put 1,2 ,3 in the event that there are 3 repeated values, as it appears in the table that I put in the example.

Here I pass code that I have been testing and it does not work for me

```
proc sql;
create table test2 AS
select *, count(t2.descripcion_tpv) AS progressive
from rank_2 as t1
LEFT JOIN RANK_2 AS T2 ON (T1.DESCRIPCION_TPV = T2.DESCRIPCION_TPV)
GROUP BY t1.descripcion_tpv
ORDER BY t1.descripcion_tpv;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a data step with `by` group processing instead.

```
proc sort data=have;
    by description;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    by description;

    if(first.description) then rank = 0;

    rank+1;
run;
```

Output:

```
CODE    DESCRIPTION COUNT   rank
NULL    FERRERO     2       1
NULL    FERRERO     1       2
NULL    KIT-KAT     3       1
NULL    KIT-KAT     3       2
NULL    KIT-KAT     3       3
```

Note that the sum statement `rank+1` is equivalent to:

```
retain rank 0;
rank = rank+1;
```